# Operating systems requirements for installing WSO2 products

Tags: wso2

Is there a place to list the recommended operating systems for installing WSO2 products?
Distribution or versions of operating systems

Answer (score 0):

Each product has documentation you can get to from their website (https://docs.wso2.com/dashboard.action) or from their GitHub repositories (https://github.com/wso2).  Each will have an Installation Guide and one of the pages will be Installation Prerequisites.  This page will list out System Requirements, Environment Compatibility and any other required software.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the tested OS/JDK list [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/compatibility/Tested+Operating+Systems+and+JDKs).

And from [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Production+Deployment+Guidelines),

> - All WSO2 Carbon-based products are Java applications that can be run    on any platform that is Oracle JDK 1.7/1.8 compliant. Also,
>     OpenJDK    is not recommended or supported.
> - All WSO2 Carbon-based products are    generally compatible with most common DBMSs. For more information,    see Working with
>     Databases.
> - It is not recommended to use Apache DS in    a production environment due to issues with scalability. Instead, it    is
>     recommended to use an LDAP like OpenLDAP for user management.
> - **On a    production deployment, it is recommended that WSO2 products are    installed on latest releases of RedHat Enterprise
>     Linux or Ubuntu    Server LTS.**
> - For environments that WSO2 products are tested with, see    Environments Tested with WSO2 Products.  If you have difficulty in
>     setting up any WSO2 product on a specific platform or with a
>     database, please contact us.